# Add act_as_commentable to public_activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed

I'm trying to create a news feed where you can comment on the activities on the feed.

I've used the gem public activity for the feed, and am now trying to integrate act_as_commentable.

The only step I've taken in the right direction is adding act_as_commentable to initializers/public_activity.rb

```
PublicActivity::Activity.class_eval do
  act_as_commentable
end
```